# Disabling LAN Causes system intrupts

Tags: freeze

disabling onboard lan (Realtek Gaming GbE Family Controller) (from windows by disabling adapter or by disabling it in bios) causes massive system interrupts.
it will go crazy up until mouse lags and results in a system freeze.

b460m ds3h mobo, Intel i5 10400 cpu. Windows 10 x64 v2004

Comment: It is likely trying to do something over the internet (updates, email and on and on).  Try connecting by Wireless (wireless USB adapter), make sure it is working.  Then disconnect the LAN again and test.

Comment: same results on wifi dongle or a mobile usb tethering. It's like something is VERY depending on onboard lan for some reason.

Comment: Try (1) from an admin command prompt: dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth   followed by SFC /SCANNOW.  Then if this does not work (2) Windows 10 Repair Install from the Microsoft Media Creation Link.  (3) Also update all your drivers including BIOS.

Comment: How are you seeing the jump in "massive system interrupts"? What tool are you using?

Comment: Using latency mon.

Comment: Ok i just made a fresh install of windows and problem is still there.

Comment: Edit: on linux the problem doesn't exist... but in windows even on pe boot it exists.